# Request Tracker 4.2.9 & Request Tracker 4.2.10

Tags: user-permissions, request-tracker

I'm trying to give different privileges configurations for several types of users (Everyone, Privileged, Non Privileged).

I have tried it using Groups, Global configurations and Queues configurations cannot obtain the output I'm looking for:

- That non privileged users can only comment (not respond) tickets.
- Assign non privileged users as owner of tickets.

So my question:

1. How to configure non privileged user to only comment on ticket cases (not to respond to requester)?
2. How to display & select a non privileged user as owner on ticket creation?

Comment: Why would you want to make unprivileged users the ticket owner? Typically the owner is the person working on the ticket, which means they at least need enough permissions to see the ticket (and usually, but not necessarily: comment, reply and close)

Comment: Hello Grant. What we need at work is the following:

A user "A" that will have contact with people/clients having troubles (that will report the bugs).
And a group "B" of users that will be analyzing the troubles, but will not have contact with the clients.

So after the group "B" has analyzed the client's case and presented recommendations (with comments only), will the user "A" communicate with the clients and close the case/ticket.

Questions:

3. Are my first two questions possible?
4. How can I configure Request Tracker the way our company wants it?

Comment: In our case the Owner of a ticket will analyze the problem but will not reply to the Requestors (clients). Only one user (that assigns owners to tickets) will reply to Requestors (clients).

Comment: Privileged doesn't mean administrator or anything like that - it means you can assign them privileges.  You can make a privileged user able to do as much or as little as you want.

Comment: Grant you are right, a privileged user is not administrator, but can be assigned specific privileges.
After reading " http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/Rights " I tried revoking all the privileges in every configuration: queues, groups of users, global configuration, and then started giving privileges on queues by group and roles, leaving the system section blank (everyone, privilege, non privilege). Finally obtaining what we needed in work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make two groups: RequestOwners and RequestProcessors.
Grant RPs 'own' and 'comment'
Grant ROs view queue, view ticket details, comment, respond, own

When a request comes in the ROs assign it to an owner or drop it in a queue (RP queue) for RPs to process; when they figure it out they will add a comment and assign it back to an RO or otherwise put it [back] into the ROs queue (ready for response to client).

This should get you the permission profile you want. Privileged doesn't mean what you want - privileged more or less means the user can have specified permissions. Since you want to specify permissions for ROs and RPs you need to make them both privileged users.

Comment: Ram you are right, privileged means the user can have specific permissions.

After reading " http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/Rights " I tried revoking all the privileges in every configuration: queues, groups of users, global configuration, and then started giving privileges on queues by group and roles, leaving the system section blank (everyone, privilege, non privilege). Finally obtaining what we needed in work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my initial questions:

1. How to configure non privileged user to only comment on ticket cases (not to respond to requester)?

Answer= Non privileged users are used to see, comment and respond tickets on the Request Tracker page. To have an inner user that can only comment but not respond the requester of a ticket, the privileges must be carefully specified on queue by the group of user and/or role that the inner user is going to have.

Note: It is very important to strip (clean) all the sections where the privileges can be configured, this include: configurations by Queue, Global configurations (by System -Everyone, Privileged user, Non privileged user-, by Roles, and by User groups). To avoid privileges overlapping.

2. How to display & select a non privileged user as owner on ticket creation?

Answer=Non privileged users cannot be displayed & selected as owners on ticket creation, only privileged users appear and can be selected as owners of a ticket.